# Android Java - Pass Class and Callback as parameter and instantiate object inside function

Tags: java, android, firebase, callback

I need your help in understanding the best way of doing this. Given the sample code below, I need to know how to pass a Class and a Callback via parameter and use them internally to instantiate an object of type Class and use the method Class.setId, and then pass the instantiated object to the Callback function. Is that possible?

```
private void loadreading(String nodeType, String tableName, String deviceId, Class ReadingSubClass, Callback updateFields) {
    readingQuery = fbDB.child(nodeType).child(tableName).child(deviceId).orderByChild("timestamp").limitToLast(1);

    readingEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                // Create new reading
                readingSubClass r = ds.getValue(ReadingSubClass.class);
                r.setId(snapshot.getKey());
                // Update fields
                updateFields(r);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            logMsg(getContext(), "Load Reading: " + error.getMessage(), true, false, false, false);
        }
    };
    readingQuery.addValueEventListener(readingEventListener);
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo it fails at the class instantiation ´´´readingSubclass r = ds.getValue...´´´. If i change the type to "var", it complains on the line below saying the setId method does not exists.

Comment: Have you tried using `ReadingSubClass readingSubClass = ds.getValue(ReadingSubClass.class);`? Does it work this way?

Comment: It won't work, since ReadingSubClass is a parameter to the function where the real class will be passed to the function.

Comment: That's not how you should handle that situation. If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5) will help.

Comment: I'm coding in Java, not Kotlin